# При запуске кроме окна windows с сообщением открывается и пустое консольное окно

Tags: main

Написал простенькую программу на C#, используя шаблон "Empty Project" в VisualStudio 2019.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace AOTD
{
    public partial class Program
    {
        static XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("aotd.xml");
        static DateTime DataNull = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);
        static DateTime DataToday = DateTime.Today;

        private static void Main()
        {
            var listAotd = xdoc.Element("data-set").Elements("record").Select(q => new
            {
                nameDoc = q.Element("namedoc").Value,
                nameSubdivision = q.Element("namesubdivision").Value,
                dateRevision = DateRevision(q.Element("daterevision").Value)
            }).Where(w => w.dateRevision.AddDays(-30) <= DataToday);

            if (listAotd.Count() > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Есть записи");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Нет записей");
            }
        }

        private static DateTime DateRevision(string daterevision)
        {
            int DayCount;
            try     // Выполняем проверку числа дней от 01.01.19 на корректность символов, допустимы только цифры
            {
                DayCount = int.Parse(daterevision);
            }
            catch (Exception)    // catch (Exception ex) "ex" - переменная передает сообщения от системы
            {
                return DataNull;
            }
            return DataNull.AddDays(DayCount - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске кроме окна windows с сообщением открывается и пустое консольное окно, которое мне не нужно. В чем я ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

В свойствах проекта необходимо изменить "Тип выходных данных" с "Консольное приложение" на "Приложение Windows".